# An intent placed inside a thread which runs with onClickListener of a button runs the intent 2-3 times varying with devices. Any way to fix this?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, runnable

Multiple intents are started by Thread varying by devices where only one intent needs to be started.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
@Override
 public void run() {
   try{
       Intent i = new Intent(this, Result.class);
       startActivity(i);
   }catch (Exception e){
      Log.d("MyClient.java", "Problem in Thread :- " + e);
      final String error = e.toString();
      new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Some Error Occured").setMessage(""+error).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, listener).setCancelable(false).create().show();
          }
      });
    }
 }
});
thread.start();
```

What I want and should happen is that the Intent i should be started for once only but instead of that :-

- 3 new intents are started in Galaxy S8+(running Oreo 8.0) & Redmi 6 Pro (running Oreo 8.1.0)
- 2 new intents are started in Moto E4 Plus (running Nougat 7.1)
- only one intent is started in LD_Player(Emulator running Lollipop 5.1.1) and Galaxy S5 (running Marshmallow 6.0.1)

Comment: why do you need a thread for it ?

Comment: Because I am using some NetworkActivity code in this class which is also enclosed in try-catch block along with this code and also an if-else statement to decide whether to start the intent or not @Blackbelt
                            `Document document = Jsoup.connect(qurl).get();`